# Никак не получается реализовать скриншот рабочей области на WPF

Tags: c#, экран

Как реализовать скриншот рабочей области на WPF?

Answer (score 1):

Что подразумевается под рабочей областью? Если все изображенное на дисплее, то скриншот можно сделать так:

```
        Bitmap printscreen = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);

        Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(printscreen as Image);

        graphics.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, printscreen.Size);

        printscreen.Save("printscreen.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```